# Обновить форму ajax кнопкой, расположенной внутри этой формы

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsf

Не получается внедрить ajax в форму.
В форме есть таблица, которая на каждой строке содержит кнопку `delete`. При ее нажатии эта таблица должна обновляться.

Пробовал так:

```
<h:form id="PriceForm">
<h:panelGroup id="StatusBlock">
<h:dataTable id="PriceTable" ....... >
<h:column> содержание </h:column>
<h:column> содержание </h:column>
<h:column> содержание </h:column>
<h:column> содержание </h:column>
<h:column> содержание </h:column>

<h:column id = "column">
<f:facet name="header">Delete</f:facet>
<h:commandButton id="ajax" action="#{priceBean.deletePriceRecord(price.id)}" value="Delete" class="">
    <f:ajax execute="@this" render=":PriceForm:PriceTable:column" />
</h:commandButton>
</h:column>
</h:dataTable>
</h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Чтобы таблица обновлялясь нужно результаты запроса вставить в таблицу.

Comment: как это можно сделать?

Comment: Это можно сделать по разному, покажите ка вы это делали.

Comment: я пока сделал так как выше написано. ну и еще вот такое есть решение. указать в рендинге саму форму. это помогает но в этом случае на кнопку приходиться нажать 2 и более раз чтобы она отработала. <h:commandButton value="Delete">
                    <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{priceBean.deletePriceRecord(price.id)}" render=":PriceForm"/>
                </h:commandButton>